# How to prove this? $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta+h)-\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta+h)-\cos(\theta)} = -\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

How to prove this?

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(\theta+h)-\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta+h)-\cos(\theta)} = -\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$$

Comment: Insert  an $h$ to right places and then use the original defenition of differentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} = f'(a)$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(\theta+h)-\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta+h)-\cos(\theta)}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin(\theta+h)-\sin(\theta)}{h}}{\frac{\cos(\theta+h)-\cos(\theta)}{h}}\\
&=\frac{\sin'(\theta)}{\cos'(\theta)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to use [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

Otherwise,

$$\dfrac{\sin(\theta+h)-\sin\theta}{\cos(\theta+h)-\cos\theta}$$

$$=\dfrac{\sin^2(\theta+h)-\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2(\theta+h)-\cos^2\theta}\cdot\dfrac{\cos(\theta+h)+\cos\theta}{\sin(\theta+h)+\sin\theta}$$

Now $\sin^2(\theta+h)-\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2(\theta+h)-(1-\cos^2\theta)=-\{\cos^2(\theta+h)-\cos^2\theta\}$

and $\sin^2(\theta+h)-\sin^2\theta\ne0$ as $h\ne0$ as $h\to0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint $\sin A-\sin B=2\cos((A+B)/2)\sin((A-B)/2)$ and $\cos A-\cos B=2\sin((B-A)/2)\sin((A+B)/2)$ one term gets cancelled  then apply limits and you will get $-\cot(\theta)=1/(-\tan(\theta))$